# Node-Gyp is returning error while trying to install brain.js

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, brain.js

I am trying to install `brain.js` on my machine. I run `npm install brain.js` but it doesn't work. It fails with an error. The error is below. I have tried to look up the issue but I can't find any answers.

```
MY INFO

NODE VERSION: v16.13.1
NPM VERISON: 8.3.0
```

Stackoverflow won't let me add the error in the description but here is a paste of the error I am encountering. https://pastebin.com/Aq8DU0M6

Answer (score -1):

**I have 0 ideas why this worked but it did.**

I had to install the program with `yarn`

```sh
yarn add brain.js
```